# ssh-agent only saving identity for current session

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I am having a problem with ssh-agent: when I add my private key to the agent (started with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, added with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/privatekey` and checked it was added with `ssh-add -l`). It works fine for that session, but when I exit and ssh back into the server and starting the agent, I get:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

I used the workaround of adding `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)` & `ssh-add ~/.ssh/privatekey` to my .zshrc, it works of course, but there must be another solution? Thanks for any help :)